# Meteor and Mongo with a typescript class having an error "Property 'Collection' does not exist on type 'typeof Mongo'." when compiling

Tags: mongodb, typescript, meteor

I'm having a console warning saying " Property 'Collection' does not exist on type 'typeof Mongo'." when compiling meteor. I'm wondering if any of you guys have experienced this and how did you solve this.

I'm using meteor/react

My typescript class code:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import MongoCollection from '../../lib/MongoCollection';

class entries extends MongoCollection {
  public collection: any;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.collection = new Mongo.Collection('entries');
  }
}

export let Entries = new entries();
```

the MongoColection.ts is

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

interface commonSchema {
  _id: string;
  createdAt?: string;
  updatedAt?: string;
}

class MongoCollection {
  collection: any;

  aggregate = (selector: object = {}, options: object = {}) => {
    return this.collection.aggregate(selector, options);
  }

  find = (selector: object = {}, options: object = {}) =>  {
    return this.collection.find(selector, options);
  }

  first = (selector: object = {}, options:object = {}) => {
    return this.collection.findOne(selector, options);
  }

  where = (selector: object = {}, options: object = {}) => {
    return this.find(selector, options).fetch();
  }

  count = (selector: object = {}, options: object = {}) => {
    return this.find(selector, options).count();
  }

  beforeInsert = (doc: commonSchema, beforeInsertAttrs: object): object => {
    const { createdAt } = doc;
    if (typeof createdAt === 'undefined') {
      doc.createdAt = moment().tz('America/New_York').format();
    }
    doc.updatedAt = moment().tz('America/New_York').format();
    _.extend(doc, beforeInsertAttrs);
    return doc;
  }

  insert = (doc, beforeInsertAttrs): string => {
    let newDoc: object = this.beforeInsert(doc, beforeInsertAttrs);
    const _id: string = this.collection.insert(newDoc);
    return _id;
  }

  update = () => {}
}

export default MongoCollection;
```

and the console warning is

```
Property 'Collection' does not exist on type 'typeof Mongo'.
```

any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the `MongoCollection`

Comment: hey @fool-dev. thanks for replying. i've added the mongo collection class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign any type of the object as like `<any>{}` if not object then not error

```
class entries extends MongoCollection {
public collection: <any>{};
constructor() {
    super();
    this.collection = new Mongo.Collection('entries');
}
};

export let Entries = new entries();
```

Comment: Hi. i tried it but IDE is giving me this error. [ts]
Type 'Collection<{}>' is not assignable to type '<any>() => {}'.
  Type 'Collection<{}>' provides no match for the signature '<any>(): {}'.

Comment: You have tried as like `<any>(): {}` which suggesting IDE